# Material UI - TS - component prop typing - Property 'x' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & y'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to take advantage of the [`component`](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-component-prop) prop from the material ui library, but i'm struggling to make it work with typescript. I would like to pass the `target` property to my `Paper` component to reach the underlying `a` component.

```js
// Next.js Link component
<Link href={url} passHref>
  <Paper
    component="a"
    target="_blank"
  >
     ...
  </Paper>
</Link>
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this TS error:

> Property 'target' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> PaperProps'.

I tried using a custom component with `PaperProps` as stated by the documentation, but I didn't succeed.

#### How do I get this example:

```js
function CustomComponent(props: TypographyProps<'a', { component: 'a' }>) {
  /* ... */
}
```

#### to work with my `Paper` component?

Comment: Why don't you use **target="_blank"** on **Link** component directly?

Comment: It wouldn't work, it's a Next.js `Link`. It doesn't accept any `target` attribute.